# what is best method to index into array

Tags: python

Lets say I am trying to get the number of different peoples names. user inputs names until they enter a -1, once -1 is entered then loop will break

Once entered then i am trying to tabulate the output something likes this

names :               John Max Joan

No of occurrences :   4    1    2

% of occurences   :   20%  10% 30%

```
#!/usr/bin/python

names = ["John","Max","Joan"]

lst = []

while True:

    lst = raw_input("What is your name?")
    if lst == "-1":
        break
    input_list = lst.split()



print "Names" '[%s]' % ' '.join(map(str, names))
```

I have no idea on how to increment the values of the names with the number of times they are entered by the user - lets say the user enters john, john, max,joan joan joan then I would need to increment john twice, max once and joan 3 times.

I know I can reference different parts of names using [0] for example which is the first item but I don't know how to increment all the relevant parts .

Comment: Increment *what*, exactly? Why don't you just use `collections.Counter`?

Comment: I am trying to increment the values of number of occurences. If john is entered 10 times then i want the value of no of occurences under john to be 10. does that make sense

Comment: No, because you don't *have* anything *"under john"* to increment. You need to start with a `0` somewhere! You need to think about this more logically.

Comment: meant to have added names=[0]*8 at  the start to set the name counters to zero

Comment: @ozgar has given a very good answer, however something to look at in the future are dicts. That way, you could use your names as keys that are associated with a value you can increment each time you see the name. Dicts are flexible and one of the strengths of Python is the simplicity of working with them (once you get used to it :)). Here's a tutorial from Google: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files?hl=en

Comment: is it not possible to do this with lists /. arrays ?

Comment: @johndoe12345 It would be possible, however since you are looking to have a value associated with a key, dicts are a natural choice. Since that value is a count, collections.Counter is the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count and accumulate the occurrences of names in the given input:

```
counter = collections.Counter()
names = ["John", "Max", "Joan"]

while True:
    lst = raw_input("What is your name?")
    if lst == "-1":
        break

    lst = [name for name in lst.strip().split() if name in names]
    names.update(collections.Counter(lst))

print "names : {}".format(" ".join(names))
print "No of occurrences : {}".format(" ".join(map(str, names.values())))
```

*Please note that, I presumed names are separated by whitespace in the input.*

Comment: this doesnt work because the print is expecting a string but its given an integer

Comment: @johndoe12345 good catch, added `map(str, ...)` to convert it into string.

Comment: ok thanks. one thing though, i want the values in names to be either john , max or joan. Your program will count and display any value like Johnny etc. I want the name values to be fixed to the 3 above so if the user enters john then i want the number of john to +1 . In other words the value i have listed above in names, i always want that line to be printed out first and then the occurences underneath

Comment: @johndoe12345 you need to filter `lst` so that only names in `names` list will be added to the counter. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Counting word frequency in a multi-word string:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

WORDS = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
ex ea commodo consequat."""


d = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for word in WORDS.split():
    d[word] += 1 

for key in ['in', 'et', 'ut', 'sed']:
    print(key, ':\t', str(d[key]))
```

output:

```
in :     0
et :     1
ut :     2
sed :    1
```

Whether one normalizes the words to lowercase depends on the problem domain; in case the questioner wants to do that with the names he receives, that'd be `data[word.lower()] += 1` in the loop, and then he may re-capitalize the first letter on output if he wishes to do that.